# HibernateTemplate is taking too much time to execute queries

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am using HibernateTemplate with Oracle Database and while executing simple queries it is taking too much time.

```
String queryString = "from document as doc where doc.name=?";
return getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString, "cloud");
```

This simple query which fetches 200 records taking 8-10 seconds.

Comment: And how many fields are in those 200 records? 1 or 100 and how many related entities are there? Next to that how complex is your graph as objects get created for each line. Also comparing plain SQL execution with hibernate execution is comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: before anything else please check the query time in database. you might be running a select with where clause on a non-indexed column.

Answer (score 0):

One first step you can take to solve this issue is to gather more information by setting "hibernate.show_sql" to "true" in your configuration files in order to see exactly what SQL is generated.  This will let you see and test the generated queries to isolate the source of the problem.

My best guess without more information is that this statement is triggering eager fetching for a large number of records.  Overuse of eager fetching is a common mistake that can significantly slow down Hibernate applications.  Hibernate's eager fetching can be very inefficient, retrieving records one at a time and running large numbers of queries against the database.